# Change array key in array_diff PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have array like this

```
$arrA = array(0 => 0, 1=>1, 2=>2 );
```

and

```
$arrB = array(0 => "0", 1 => "1");
```

and i search difference the array with

```
$lol = array_diff($arrA, $arrB);
var_dump($lol);
```

but the output of key array start from 2 not from 0 like this :

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

my question is how to change key of the array in variable `$lol` to `0(zero)` again ?

thank you

Comment: just apply `array_values` to `$lol` to effectively reset the keys

Comment: @Ghost thank you, solved sir why i can't voted up your question by the way ?

Comment: this is a comment box, sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Hey use array_values() function on your output.

```
$arrA = array(0 => 0, 1=>1, 2=>2 );
$arrB = array(0 => "0", 1 => "1");

$lol = array_values(array_diff($arrA, $arrB));
var_dump($lol);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result begins with zero, just sort it before output.

```
sort($lol);

var_dump($lol);
```